# How can I determine the cell corresponding to a data field's name in an Excel pivot table?

Tags: excel, ms-office, pivot-table, openxml, spreadsheetml

Suppose I have the following Excel pivot table:

[image: Excel pivot table]

The definition of the pivot table from pivotTable1.xml contains the following relevant snippets:

```
<location ref="I8:M26" firstHeaderRow="1" firstDataRow="2" firstDataCol="1" rowPageCount="1" colPageCount="1"/>

<dataFields count="1">
<dataField name="Custom Sum of Amount" fld="3" baseField="1" baseItem="0"/>
</dataFields>
```

Given these pieces of data, together with the rest of the definition, is it possible to accurately determine the cell (I8) where the "Custom Sum of Amount" is placed? Unfortunately I couldn't find something helpful in the SpreadsheetML specification and I don't want to rely on unbacked assumptions about its location.

Also, it would very helpful for me if I could also determine the cell location for the other auto-generated captions, such as "Custom Row Labels Caption", "Custom Column Labels Caption" and "Custom Grand Total Caption".

Comment: Can I ask why you want to identify it? Just want to see if there is another way to achieve what it is you want to do.

Comment: @jeffreyweir I'm working on an application that allows users to modify the contents of a cell in a pivot table. After they do it, the table will be auto-refreshed in the new Excel file (using the refreshOnLoad attribute in pivot cache definition). However, i want to retain the value written by users in the cells corresponding to data field names so that i can update the name attribute of the dataField tag besides auto-refreshing the table. Otherwise the new value will be lost.

Answer (score -1):

Work out the Values field that you want the info for, then use:
pf.LabelRange.Address

Comment: I'm not sure what API you refer to. I am working strictly at the level of the SpreadsheetML XML files making up the XLSX file.

Comment: That's VBA. Apologies...I didn't realize you weren't working in VBA.